# Is there a way to combine two different strings alphabetically using stack in C?

Tags: c, data-structures, stack

Here is the program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *stack;
int stackindex = 0;

int push(char in){
    if (stack==NULL) {
        stack = (char *) malloc (sizeof(char));
    }
    else {
        stack = (char *) realloc(stack, sizeof(char)* ++stackindex);
    }
    stack[stackindex] = in;
    return 1;
}

char pop(){
    return stack[stackindex--];
}

void show() {
    for (int i=stackindex; i>=0;i--) {
        printf("%c", pop());
    }
}

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        int k = strlen(argv[i]);
        int j;
        for (int j = 0; j < k ; j++) {
            char in = argv [i] [j];
            push( in );
        }
    for (j = i; j < k; j++){
        char temp;
            if (stack[i] > stack[j]) {
                temp = stack[j];
                stack[j] = stack[i];
                stack[i] = temp;
        }
        if (i, argc-1) push(' ');
    }
    show();
    return 0;
    }
}
```

I've been trying to make an output from the string "im loving" alphabetically in descending order (ASCII based) using command line arguments like this: vonmliig, but the output was "m i" instead.

Comment: What's the point of the loop that sets `in` but never uses it?

Comment: Where do you declare `stack`?

Comment: Is this your entire program?  How are values written to `stack`?  Do mean to do anything with `in`?

Comment: Your indentation looks wrong. Like you have misplaced the `}` of the first `for` loop in `main`.

Comment: Are you sure `if (i, argc-1) push(' ');` is what you mean?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not, I'm currently stuck at that line and still trying to figure out the appropriate code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to sort as you build the stack. I would build the stack first, then sort.

```
int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    if (argc >= 3) {
        // Build stack
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
            int k = strlen(argv[i]);
            for (int j = 0; j < k ; j++) {
                push(argv[i][j]);
            }
        }
        // Sort
        for (int i = 0; i < stackindex; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j < stackindex; j++){
                if (stack[i] > stack[j]) {
                    char temp = stack[j];
                    stack[j] = stack[i];
                    stack[i] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        show();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also, there is an error in the handling of `stackindex` in `push()`.

```
int push(char in)
{
    char *temp = realloc(stack, stackindex + 1);
    if (!temp) {
        // Handle error
        return -1;
    }
    stack = temp;
    stack[stackindex++] = in;
    return 1;
}

char pop()
{
    if (stackindex) return stack[--stackindex];
    else return 0;
}

void show()
{
    do {
        printf("%c", pop());
    } while (stackindex);
}
```